# calling view in SQL to find records

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a view `article_avis_favorable` but when I made this query to search articles but using some specifications:

```
SELECT blabla
FROM Table
WHERE id_article in article_avis_favorable;
```

It displays an error message `Erreur SQL : ORA-00904: "ARTICLE_AVIS_FAVORABLE" : identificateur non valide 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

Comment: Usually with an "in" you need a subquery with another table's SELECT query - the in is checking another table right?

Comment: Yes but, I don't know... Check my view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider your view as a table

```
SELECT blabla
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN article_avis_favorable v ON t. id_article = v. id_article
```

Or

```
SELECT blabla
FROM Table 
WHERE id_article in (SELECT id_article FROM article_avis_favorable);
```

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if you consider an acceptable answer ;)